# JSP on Heroku - "Unable to compile class for JSP"

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, heroku, el

I'm working on a Spring MVC service app which I planned to deploy on Heroku. While I was deploying the app with `git push` and the app was dependent on Jetty, everything was working fine. Then I decided to remove Jetty from the application, split the app into several modules, use Maven to bundle it into a WAR and deploy that WAR to Heroku (effectively deploying my app to Tomcat 7). Service part of the application continued to work properly, but JSPs started to throw weird exceptions:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/createOrder.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<Boolean>, PageContext, null, boolean) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
9: </head>
10: <body>
11: <c:choose>
12: <c:when test="${success}">
13:     Order successfully created
14: </c:when>
15: <c:otherwise>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

It appears as if EL doesn't work.

Did anyone else run into this or similar problems, and does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question... I did two things to resolve this problem:
1) I have removed the leftover Jetty dependencies from Maven pom.xml file; Jetty was used only for local testing anyway, so this didn't cause any more problems
2) I have added a reference to `org.springframework.ui.Model` as a parameter to all the Spring MVC controller methods that were redirecting to a JSP page, alongside the existing `Map<String, Object>` parameter; service methods - those that return XML or JSON - were left untouched. I have also copied all members of the `Map<String, Object>` parameter into the Model parameter.

My guess is that removing Jetty dependencies from pom.xml did the trick, but I've also implemented the second fix for good measure.